# How can I make VS Code sign my commits?

Tags: linux, fedora, flatpak, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble getting `vscode` to commit changes I make to files. I am currently running Fedora 35 Silverblue, so I'm using the flatpak version of VS Code.
I have set up my `.gitconfig` as it should be and ran `echo "test" | gpg --clear-sign` to get the dialog box asking for the password to my gpg-key.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I've tried punching holes in the security of the whole VS Code flatpak config file to make sure that nothing is stopping it from interacting with system files etc. but this doesn't seem to help, either.

This is the setup of my `.gitconfig`:

```
       | File: /var/home/myuser/.gitconfig
   1   │ [user]
   2   │     email = my@email
   3   │     name = myname
   4   │     signingKey = mykey
   5   │ [commit]
   6   │     gpgSign = true
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the combo `git` + `flatpak` + `vscode` doesn't play well... [there are some issues which haven't been resolved, according to the vscode GH repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43809).